# Finding coordinates so that no line intersect each other

Tags: geometry

This is an exercise I came up with, but can't solve myself.... Here goes:

Say you receive as input a list of N nodes. Each node n is connected to one or more nodes. The input could look something like:

```
Node A is linked to node B and C
Node B is linked to node A and C
Node C is linked to node A and B
```

The goal is to find a function that maps each node to a coordinate in a plane in such a way that the straight lines connecting each node do not intersect each other.

The example above is trivial: As long as the nodes are not all on the same axis it will work, but it gets lot harder with more nodes and more links between them. I'm assuming some inputs do not have any valid answer, but I don't see how you can prove it.

Comment: This is a question about planar graphs.  There are algorithms that detect planarity.  Google "planar graph" and you'll get thousands (at least) of hits.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know enough about the problem to know what to google for, but it does look like planar graph is what I'm looking for :)

Comment: It was my pleasure.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question, summarizing your findings.